# How to get Chrome headless to autofill username / passwords?

Tags: google-chrome, autofill, google-chrome-headless

How can I get Chrome launched in [headless mode](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) to autofill any stored username and passwords?

Launched normally from the command line, autofill works as expected. But with the `--headless` option, autofill does not seem to be happening (for the same pages & fields).  I'm using the [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) to remotely control the browser in both cases.

I am specifying a `--user-data-dir` that is the same in both "headed" and headless cases.

Version info: Google Chrome 62.0.3202.94 on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: Does this happen on all pages or just some?  You might have to demonstrate the link.  I just tried headless chrome populating login and pass and it worked perfectly for me. It could be the method you autofill or even the site.

Comment: I've also encountered this issue and have tried a ton of things. I suspect maybe after all the questions about how to disable autofill/password manager in chromedriver, perhaps support has been removed?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe worth to check it. It has a `password-store` flag, for defining which encryption storage to use. Here it is [link](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/headless/app/headless_shell_switches.cc)